# AndroidX migration - data binding error msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:visibility' with parameter type int

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, runtimeexception, androidx

I'm migrating a project to AndroidX and have the following error :

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
>          android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding errors.
>       ****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:visibility' with parameter type int on
>   androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout

And the layout having the issue is :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_centerInParent="true"
  android:visibility="@{myVar == STRING_SUCCESS ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}">
```

I don't know where to start ... Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout`

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Can you explain where the issue comes from please ? I have bunch of others like this ...

Comment: You just need to use the layout itself. Try pressing Ctrl+click the class `ConstraintLayout` in `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout` (in the xml). You'll get the actual class implementation, try again with your original 'layout' and discover that there is nothing behind it

Comment: Life saver @ronginat !

Comment: Just write the view name and let the IDE fill it for you.

Comment: I had the same problem but with a different layout, `cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:visibility' with parameter type int on android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout` and I can't figure out the package to use for `TextInputLayout`

Comment: `android.material` is now `com,google.android.material`. Add `implementation com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha05`  to your gradle (if you didn't already). Then use `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout`