# Adding buildFeatures { viewBinding true } results in "Cannot find a setter for <... android:visibility> that accepts parameter type 'int'

Tags: android, android-viewbinding

I want to start using `viewBinding` in [our project](https://github.com/mycelium-com/wallet-android) but the mere addition of the configuration results in a compile error:

```
android {
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
        viewBinding true // new line and only change
    }
```

results in:

```
e: /home/leo/StudioProjects/android-wallet/mbw/build/generated/source/kapt/btctestnetDebug/com/mycelium/wallet/DataBinderMapperImpl.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
import com.mycelium.wallet.databinding.FragmentBequantAccountBindingImpl;
                                      ^
  symbol:   class FragmentBequantAccountBindingImpl
  location: package com.mycelium.wallet.databinding




Cannot find a setter for <com.mycelium.wallet.databinding.ItemBequantSearchBinding app:visibility> that accepts parameter type 'int'

If a binding adapter provides the setter, check that the adapter is annotated correctly and that the parameter type matches.
```

The offending code is:

```
    <data>

        <import type="android.view.View" />

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.mycelium.bequant.market.viewmodel.AccountViewModel" />
    </data>
...
<include
    android:id="@+id/searchBar"
    layout="@layout/item_bequant_search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="@{viewModel.searchMode ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}" removing="this line fixes compilation"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/hideZeroBalance" />
```

Changing the offending line to any of

```
android:visibility="@{viewModel.searchMode ? `visible` : `gone`}"
app:visibility="@{viewModel.searchMode ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
```

results in similar errors.

I read I might have to define a `BindingAdapter` but why and where?

I tried adding

```
    @BindingAdapter("visibility")
    fun setVisibility(target: View, visible: Boolean) {
        target.visibility = if (visible) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
    }
```

to AccountFragment which inflates above xml file changing the xml to

```
android:visibility="@{viewModel.searchMode}"
```

but this appears to have no effect.

Both `fragment_bequant_account.xml` and `item_bequant_search.xml` [use `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout` instead of `androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55571785/969478).

I tried to put a `@BindingAdapter` into the `AccountViewModel` [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64673518/how-can-i-binding-different-value-for-androidlayout-marginleft-based-livedatab#comment114585528_64679628) but with no success.

Comment: Was your data binding working before or is that something you added too?

Comment: Data binding is working since many commits. Hundreds. The error comes after adding the line marked with `// new line and only change`.

Comment: Databinding already includes ViewBinding. No need to add that line. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#data-binding

Comment: In the linked document I don't see any claims about one including the other but I see `tools:viewBindingIgnore="true"` which added to the one problematic layout fixes my issue, so thank you for making me read that document!!! I'm happy but still curious why this one `visibility` is not like the others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem in my project. I used databinding in my code and had `dataBinding true` in the gradle. As soon as I added `viewBinding true` I got the same error pointing to the xml line `android:visibility="@{viewModel.searchMode ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"`

**To fix**, I added the `tools:viewBindingIgnore="true"` attribute to the root view of a certain layout file so that layout is ignored while generating binding classes.

You can see documentation on the `tools:viewBindingIgnore="true"` attribute at https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#data-binding

Comment: Looks like [that's the hack we used, too](https://github.com/mycelium-com/wallet-android/commit/86f5f4d) back then. Still a hack :(

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the viewBinding trying to create the binding class of the layout in the include.
It seems that the binding class created for the main layout(dataBinding) manages the included layout in a different way when viewBinding = true and don't understand it's attrs

As James said ***tools:viewBindingIgnore="true"*** is the solution, in this case it must be in the included layout(layout="@layout/item_bequant_search").

Every reused layout must have ***tools:viewBindingIgnore="true"*** to avoid this issues

Answer (score 3):

I got similar error and this is my solution:
You only add tag '<layout.../layout>' to all include layout like this:
In main layout:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data>

    <import type="android.view.View" />

    <variable
        name="viewId"
        type="Integer" />
</data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bg">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/img_no_data"
        layout="@layout/layout_no_data"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="@{viewId==0? View.VISIBLE: View.GONE}"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_camera"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

In include layout: add tag '<layout...' too:

```
<layout>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_16sdp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_16sdp"
        android:src="@drawable/bg_no_data"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="986:817"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

          
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Done! Hope this help you.

Comment: What "tag" are you talking about? Can you clearly mark what you added where? Some `<!-- this is what we added -->` on the respective line in the example or so.

Comment: sorry, I don't check it again before post answer. tag I talking about is '<layout>'

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this statement

```
app:visibility="@{viewModel.searchMode ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
```

it evaluates and pass `View.VISIBLE` or `View.GONE` to the binding adapter method,But

```
@BindingAdapter("visibility")
    fun setVisibility(target: View, visible: Boolean)
```

As your method signature says it expects a boolen but evaluation results in `int` i.e. either `View.VISIBLE` or `View.GONE`.

The issue can be solved by removing the evaluation and passing the boolean directly.

```
app:visibility="@{viewModel.searchMode}"
```

I assument `viewModel.searchMode` is a boolean variable.

Lets you create a kotlin file Named BindingAdapters.kt

Paste this method directly there

```
@BindingAdapter("visibility")
fun setVisibility(target: View, visible: Boolean) {
    target.visibility = if (visible) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
}
```

else lets say you have a class `BindingAdapters` in a file BindingAdapters.kt

```
class BindingAdapters{
     
  companion object{
    
    @BindingAdapter("visibility")
    @JvmStatic// it is important
    fun setVisibility(target: View, visible: Boolean) {
        target.visibility = if (visible) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: I do not have a BindingAdapter for this property. The code you mention was an attempt at introducing one and yes, I changed my xml accordingly to set Boolean but that's in the list of failed attempts and I don't understand why in this and only this case I suddenly would need a BindingAdapter. It should, like in all the other cases, just set the standard visibility property like before enabling view binding.

Comment: @Giszmo can you elaborate a little on what changes you have done and still did not work

Comment: If you could just let me know that your current is the same as the code in the question or there is any change in it?

Comment: As mentioned on the comments I'm good with a little hack but still curious what was the issue. We have a big code base with hundreds of layouts, dozens of which were already using data binding. `android:visibility="@{ viewModel... ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"` can be found 39 times in the project. Only one of those has above issue.

Comment: have you called `binding.executePendingBindings()`? for this binding?

Comment: there is no `executePendingBindings` in the project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228124/discussion-between-giszmo-and-rahat).